# At what size should I malloc structs?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc

Most examples using structs in C use `malloc` to assign the required size block of memory to a pointer to that struct. However, variables with basic types (`int`, `char` etc.) are allocated to the stack and it is assumed that enough memory will be available.

I understand the idea behind this is that memory may not be available for larger structs so we use `malloc` to ensure we do indeed have enough memory but in the case of our struct being small is this really necessary? For example if a struct only consists of three ints, surely I am always fine to assume there is enough memory?

So really my question boils down to what are the best practises in C regarding when it is necessary to `malloc` variables and what is the justification?

Comment: It's not (generally) a question of how big a struct is, it's about the lifetime of it. An object allocated on the stack only exists as long as that object is in scope, so if you want to return a pointer to a struct, then you _have_ to use malloc.

Comment: It can be a question of how big it is if you are operating in an environment with limited stack size. I gather that this happens in MS IIS, as I found myself having to modify a library to reduce its stack usage for the benefit of people using it in that environment. In this case the larger structures were several kilobytes, but I don’t know what the stack limit was offhand. In MSVS you can get compiler warnings for using too much stack. On AIX if your run out of stack it does weird things. VMS expands the stack automatically up to VM quota (I think).

Comment: If you only use a struct within a single function it would be normally absurd to allocate it (and risk failing to free it) unless you hit the limits I mentioned in my previous comment. Up to several hundred bytes, there should be no problem.

Comment: @PJTraill Okay so assuming I'm not interested in keeping it around outside of the scope, it's generally fine to use small structs without allocating the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good code gets re-used.  Good code have few size limitations. Write good code.

Use `malloc()` whenever there is anything more than trivial buffer sizes.

1. Buffer size to write an `int`:  The needed buffer size is at most `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3`.  Use a fixed buffer.
2. Buffer size to write a `double` as in `sprintf(buf, "%f",...`:  The needed buffer size could be thousands of bytes: use `malloc()`.  Or use `sprintf(buf, "%e",...` and use a fixed buffer.
3. Forming a file path name could involve thousands of `char`.  Use `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you don't have to allocate memory is when you statically allocate memory, which is what happens when you have a statement like:

```
int number = 5;
```

You can always write it as:

```
int *pNumber = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

but you have to make sure to free it or you will be leaking memory.

You can do the same thing with a struct (instead of dynamically allocating memory for it, statically allocate):

```
struct some_struct_t myStruct;
```

and access members by:

```
myStruct.member1 = 0;
etc...
```

The big difference between dynamic allocation and static is whether that data is available outside of your current scope.  With static allocation, it's not.  With dynamic it is, but you have to make sure to free it.

Where you run into trouble is when you have to return a structure (or a pointer to it) from a function. You either have to dynamically allocate inside the function which is returning it or you have to pass in a pointer to an externally (dynamically or statically) allocated structure which the function can then work with.

Comment: Did you intend to write `string` in `string some_struct_t myStruct;` ?

Comment: It was a typo.  Fixed.

Comment: A possible drawback is that `malloc` allocates memory in the *global* memory pool, and thus allocating and freeing lots of objects can lead to memory fragmentation. Most implementations will reuse freed memory as soon as possible, and C lacks garbage collection.

Comment: @Jongware: yes, this is especially troublesome on embedded systems where memory is in the 10-100Kb range and fragmentation happens fairly quickly.